# Can Adobe Air do this?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air, icc

I've written a lot of JavaScript before, and adobe air looks really interesting, my question is can Adobe Air:

- Access ICC profiles stored on a users computer
- Detect which ICC profile the monitor is currently using
- Use the SDK for specialist USB hardware
- Do all this one both Windows and Mac computers

Thanks for any information.  If not, any workarounds, or other potential solutions?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this, too. (btw: you might want to add the icc tag to this q)

Comment: i've removed my answer since you've posted a bounty and since my answer isn't definitive.  answer repost as comment: i'm pretty sure all that you want to do, while it might be a bit difficult, is totally possible by using flash.desktop.NativeProcess

i believe the most challenging will be communicating with your USB hardware, although you can write your own wrapper for a serial proxy (like TinkerProxy), or even write and call your own serial proxy if you know how, to communicate with a USB device over a socket. Mike Chambers details how to communicated with Arduino using a proxy on his blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer since I've never attempted to do any of it, but I'm pretty sure AIR doesn't have specialized tools for managing ICC Profiles. However I know [Java does](http://www.science.uva.nl/ict/ossdocs/java/jdk1.3/docs/api/java/awt/color/ICC_ColorSpace.html), so you could easily use [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) to bridge and get the data. Same thing with the USB thing.

I'm naming Java because it comes to mind and is available in both win and mac, but you could eventually use any other native process for each OS.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/color_correction_as3.html

This may provide further information on the subject, it talks about icc profiles and how swfs use them.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 Access ICC profiles stored on a users computer

  Not possible. Maybe you can check FluorineFX (windows only)
- 2 Detect which ICC profile the monitor is currently using

  Not possible. Maybe you can check FluorineFX (windows only)
- 3 Use the SDK for specialist USB hardware

  Do not really understand, but there is support 
  for detecting usb devices and usb changes
- 4 Do all this one both Windows and Mac computers

  point 3 must run on both windows and mac

Answer (score 0):

> Access ICC profiles stored on a users
>   computer

http://www.apponic.com/free-downloads-259/adobe-icc-profiles-cs4/

I would say NO rather than redirecting you to some third party and then scratching up your head.

> Detect which ICC profile the monitor
>   is currently using

**NO**

Use the SDK for specialist USB hardware

> **Yes**, but not fully supported. You need to go to native bridge support
>   for certain things.
>
> Do all this one both Windows and Mac
>   computers

It should.